# Why my edit text is not editable on Android 4.4 & 5.0?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, editing

I am using an edit text with some predefined(135dp) height & maximum limit of 140 characters. I am using max length for setting maximum limit & input type as text multiline. Now when i add 140 characters on my Android 4.1.2 device & edit it using backspace key, it is working fine but when same is repeated on an Android 4.4 & 5.0 devices, it doesn't edit the edit text. However if i tap 5-6 times it get worked sometime. I am unable to think about what is the issue with my edit text.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Below is the xml code for my edit text.

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/orderConfirmationMessageEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:hint="Type your message here"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ff7f6c5f"
                    android:textColorHint="#ff7f6c5f"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/order_cursor_background"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLength="140"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_edittext_background">
                </EditText>
```

Comment: Please add some code what you have do...!!

Comment: I'm thinking maybe its an issue elsewhere in your XML. Where does this EditText appear in your layout.

Comment: What do you mean by not editable? Is it like you can type some text and then cannot delete it ? or what ?

Comment: change this android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

Comment: It is not editable only when maximum limit is reached, i.e, 140 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I have overcome this issue by disabling the auto suggestions for my edit text.

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/orderConfirmationMessageEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:hint="Type your message here"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#ff7f6c5f"
                    android:textColorHint="#ff7f6c5f"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/order_cursor_background"
                    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxLength="140"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_edittext_background">
                </EditText>
```